# Typo3 FE User assign to FEUserGroup

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-6.2.x

I'm creating a FEUser programmatically (works fine) in the second Step I want to assign this FE User to an existing FEUsergroup.

I Thought it works fine but it didn't. In database the entry is set and the counter goes up.

But If i check the usergroup in List-View there are no users inside :(

My code looks like this:

```
$usergroup = $this->FrontendUserGroupRepository->findByUid($this->request->getArgument(self::USRGROUP));

$newFEUser = new \Typo3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser();
$newFEUser->setUsername($this->userfunctions->genuserNAME($newPruefling->getVorname(), $newPruefling->getNachname()));
$randomPW = $this->passfunctions->genpassword();
$saltedPW = $this->passfunctions->hashPassword($randomPW);
$newFEUser->setPassword($saltedPW);
$newFEUser->setNAME($randomPW);
$newFEUser->setFirstNAME($newPruefling->getVorname());
$newFEUser->setLastNAME($newPruefling->getNachname());
$newFEUser->setEmail($this->request->getArgument(self::EMAIL));

// Wenn Usergroup vorhanden dann wird diese gesetzt.
$newFEUser->addUsergroup($usergroup);

$this->FrontendUserRepository->add($newFEUser);
```

Whats going wrong? Have I forgotten something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have your users in a sysfolder you have to give your users the `pid` of your sysfolder. Otherwise you will not see any users in your List View.

Comment: okay .. how can I handle it if I would offer a solution for both ways?

Comment: try `$newFEUser->setPid($thePidOfyourSysfolderHere);` in your code.

Comment: but from where do I get the PID of the sysfolder??

Comment: I don't think that you can use the list view if your users have a pid of 0. So I would always store your records in a sysfolder.

Comment: Move your mouse on the icon of the sysfolder in the pagetree. You will see the page id.

Comment: yeah of course thats one possibility. but Probably there are several Sysfolders with different PIDs 

is there a possibility to get the pid of sysfolder surrounding the usergroup?

(I want to publish the extension in ter so I need a universal solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69893/discussion-between-jay-dinse-and-felix).

Comment: PID must be set!

And Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `new object` but use the `ObjectManager` of TYPO3. Otherwise this will not work.

`$newFEUser = $this->objectManger->get(\Typo3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser::class);`

Comment: okay ... I added the injenction and reinstalled so I can use Object manager, but the code you've posted dosn't work ... got an error in this line. `Call to a member function get() on a non-object in ... ` I also tried this: `$newFEUser = $this->objectManager->get('\Typo3\CMS\Extbase\Domain\Model\FrontendUser');` works without error but dosn't solve the problem